# How to make SUBJECT Substitutions in Sendgrid Swift SmtpTransport?

Tags: swiftmailer, sendgrid

I am using Swift SmtpTransport as it seems to be the recommended way.

However the documentation I found dos not show how to achieve Subject Substitutions.

- (This is what I am using) https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php-example/blob/master/smtp-php-example.php
- https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
- http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#quick-reference-for-sending-a-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on [Github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php-example/issues/3), answering here too, for folks future reference.

To use the SMTPAPI to substitute for subjects, you'll need substitution tags in the subject of the email and then include the `x-smtpapi` header with substitution tags defined.

Using the [SendGrid SMTPAPI Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-php):

```
<?php
...
$message->setSubject('[sendgrid-php-example] Owl named %yourname%');
$header           = new Smtpapi\Header();
$header->addSubstitution("%yourname%", array("Mr. Owl"))->
...
```